# SQL Anywhere 9 - Second query from another table

Tags: sql

I have the following query to search our database for duplicate patients.

```
SELECT count((Pquery.Last_Name || '_' || Pquery.First_Name|| '_' || Pquery.Date_Of_Birth)) as PatientCount,

(Pquery.Last_Name || '_' || Pquery.First_Name|| '_' || Pquery.Date_Of_Birth) as PatientString

FROM
(SELECT Name AS Last_Name, Other_Names AS First_Name, DOB as Date_Of_Birth
FROM dba.patient) as Pquery
GROUP BY PatientString
HAVING PatientCount > 1
ORDER BY PatientString ASC, PatientCount DESC;
OUTPUT TO 'c:\duplicates.csv'
```

This query works and finds duplicate records but I need to add another field into the query from another table.

I need to find the operator who performed an exam.

I want to run the second query on the result of the first query as the Operator may not always be the same person.

The second query is...

```
select operator from exam
```

I'm not sure how to add this into the current query so I get the operator who performed the exam.

I know if there were two/three records for each patient, it may be a different operator. Would it be possible to either keep both or ignore one.

Sorry for the vague query.

Thanks

Tried wrapping the query but can't seem to get the correct format.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.